# fetch SQLdata without column name in php

Tags: php, mysql

please tell me how to fetch data from MySql database in below format.

Now, i am getting data in below format

```
$sql="SELECT c.ad_id FROM `category_rel` c INNER JOIN tbl_category_master d ON c.category_id= d.fld_category_id WHERE d.fld_category_name IN ($category)";
$result1=$con->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $output[] = $row;
       }
$ids=json_encode(array($output));
```

Result:
`[[{"ad_id":"2"},{"ad_id":"11"},{"ad_id":"28"},{"ad_id":"62"},{"ad_id":"64"}]]`

But, I want in the below format:

```
["2","11","28","62"]
```

it should not come with the column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$output[] = $row['ad_id'];` instead of `$output[] = $row;`

[Edit]
Also remove array() function :

```
$sql="SELECT c.ad_id FROM `category_rel` c INNER JOIN tbl_category_master d ON c.category_id= d.fld_category_id WHERE d.fld_category_name IN ($category)";
$result1=$con->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $output[] = $row['ad_id'];
       }
$ids=json_encode($output);
```

Regards.

Comment: She faced the data as `assoc`.

Comment: I update the post as I don't see you use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, have you try ?

Comment: Sir, this is not implode. It show invalid argument. @Jean-Luc B.

Comment: Can you explain ? Does ad_id can be null ? result empty ? In this case add `$output = array()`, before while loop, it's good practice to init your vars even if php is permissive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from while loop then use it:

```
$sql="SELECT c.ad_id FROM `category_rel` c INNER JOIN tbl_category_master d ON c.category_id= d.fld_category_id WHERE d.fld_category_name IN ($category)";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $output[] = $row['ad_id']; //may be this will help Not sure the structure
}
$ids = json_encode(array($output));
```

If you need it from the output array then just use this:

```
$json = '[[{"ad_id":"2"},{"ad_id":"11"},{"ad_id":"28"},{"ad_id":"62"},{"ad_id":"64"}]]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);


$arr = array_column($arr[0], 'ad_id');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 28
    [3] => 62
    [4] => 64
)
```

Comment: Its works but not me ..I want in ['2', '11', '28', '62','64'] this format ... Because i need to use these values in next SQl Statement under IN clause.

Comment: so you can use the `implode` function. As you already accept other answer so best of luck.